# how to group by and sample unique rows that are not repeated in other groups

Tags: python, pandas, random, unique, sample

My dataframe contains three columns: `ID1`, `ID2`, `count`. For each `ID1` value, there are multiple `ID2` values sharing the same count number. My goal is to randomly select a unique `ID2` value for `ID1`, but because some `ID1` have the same count, so they select from the same group of `ID2`, and each `ID1` thus does not match a unique `ID2`. How can I remove the previously selected `ID2`?

df

```
index   ID1     cnt ID2
96333   48740   142 14145
96334   48740   142 23140
96335   48740   142 26850
96336   48740   142 159025
96349   148240  142 14145
96350   148240  142 23140
96351   148240  142 26850
96352   148240  142 159025
```

my current code `df.groupby("ID1").sample(n = 1, random_state = 5)` created

```
index   ID1     cnt ID2
96333   48740   142 14145
96349   148240  142 14145
```

expected df

```
index   ID1     cnt ID2
96333   48740   142 14145
96352   148240  142 159025
```

One solution is that looping through the dataframe, remove the selected rows and using the updated df for the next sampling, but it will take a long time if the df is large.

Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby("ID1").sample(n = 1, random_state = 5)` gives me the expected output.

Comment: it's randomly sampling, this is by chance it gives a different ID2, but for my larger df with more groups, it does not always give a unique ID2 for each ID1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `pivot` on ID1/ID2 and get the diagonals. This will ensure unique combinations.

Then apply per cnt if needed:

```
def unique(df):
    idx = np.diagonal(df.pivot('ID1', 'ID2', 'index'))
    return df[df['index'].isin(idx)]

out = unique(df)

# or per group
out = df.groupby('cnt', group_keys=False).apply(unique)
```

Output:

```
   index     ID1  cnt    ID2
0  96333   48740  142  14145
5  96350  148240  142  23140
```

*NB. with the above function, the output is deterministic as the `pivot` sorts the columns. If you want a random output, shuffle the columns before getting the diagonal.*

```
def unique(df):
    idx = np.diagonal(df.pivot('ID1', 'ID2', 'index')
                        .sample(frac=1, axis=1))
    return df[df['index'].isin(idx)]
```